# Need the right .htaccess configuration

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have a domain called test.com. 
Now my index.html is situated in /public_html/client/frontend/questionnaire/index.html, so I can access it in my browser via http://test.com/client/frontend/questionnaire/index.html.

What I want to achieve is:
* As soon as a user enters the url http://test.com, he or she should directly access the index.html
* Restrict the user so that he can only access this index.html file and not other directories on the server.

I think it should work somehow with the correct .htaccess configuration.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ client/frontend/questionnaire/index.html [L]
```

Here `Options -Indexes` is used to disable directory listing.

Comment: That is very cool, thanks anubhava :) Just one more question: In my index.html, I have some references to external filex (e.g. js, css). Now the paths referring to these files are incorrect.

Let's say I have a folder called css with a style.css file in it.
My index.html has the following reference to this file: 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

Do I have to change all the reference by hand or is there another trick how I could manage this issue?

Comment: For that you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Hm, with this base attribute, the path is now http://example.com/css/style.css . But when I put the path to the file into the base-attribute, it works. So thanks much for that again :)